# How is this answer (3454) "personal opinion"?

Tags: discussion

This answer of mine was deleted as "personal opinion":

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3454

I am not sure why: I cite works that confirm the effect that the question was asking about, and explain the graphs that were shown in the question.

Is this just an error?  Or, if not, can someone explain why the answer is "personal opinion"?

Comment: The link was broken, I think this is the right one, correct?

Comment: @Sklivvz - Yes, that's the one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer had three paragraphs. The first was referenced but quite poor in information:

> I think the Wikipedia article covers the support for this phenomenon adequately in its "supporting studies" section. There's no reason to doubt that it's a real effect given the number of confirmations.

I agree it's referenced, albeit only a tad better than a "one liner answer", by itself.

The other two paragraphs are your personal opinion on the question (the first) and the given paper (the second).

> The rest is a matter of semantics. If you say "X has a high self-appraisal", do you mean that X thinks they're better than they actually are, or that X thinks they're better than almost everyone else? If you are terrible but you think you're average, you have a huge error in your perception, but depending on your interpretation you will answer the "high self-appraisal" question either yes (relative) or no (absolute).
>
> I think it's clear from context and the discussion of the paper that they're talking about relative appraisal. The graphs are really quite clear about three things: (1) On average, people overestimate their ability; (2) Non-average people think they're more average than they really are (to such an extent that it can even overcome trend (1)); (3) The discrepancy between ability and perception is particularly bad at the bottom end. Whether (3) is explained by (1) + (2) is not clear to me from the data.

They are evidently, IMO, not presenting any evidence beyond what the OP already has.

For these reasons, the "citation need" banner was added May 6 '12, almost 3 years ago!

Yesterday I removed it as part of a larger sweep on ancient post-noticed answers.

If you like we can reinstate the first paragraph, but you should at least expand it including the sources you mention.

Comment: If the author of a question has a different interpretation of various phrasings than do the authors they cite, is there any way to demonstrate this aside from contacting the cited authors?  My point was supposed to be--perhaps not made clearly--that the authors are talking about relative confidence since the data is completely consistent with that, completely inconsistent with absolute confidence, and we generally can assume that the authors of a paper have at least a basic idea of what their data shows.  (Also, I was never aware that the question was flagged for needing a citation.)

Comment: @RexKerr if you are disagreeing with the OP on the claim or its interpretation, then you should comment on the question -- after all if the researches do not claim as the OP thinks, there should be no question.

Comment: Fair enough.  If you restore the "this is reproducible" first paragraph, I'll pull out a citation or two to underline that point and move the "you are misinterpreting their claims" bit to a comment.

Comment: There was too much to put in a comment, and I think the evidence is very solid that the original question is mistaken about what is claimed, so I put it in the answer (with quotes etc.).  Please let me know if this still seems too much a matter of opinion.